# Xticks not showing at all

Tags: python, xticks

I wonder why my graph is not showing any xticks at all?
my code:

```
    ax = df.plot(x='A', y='B', marker = 'D', markersize=4)
    ax.set_xbound(lower=-40, upper=40)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(40, -40, 4), rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing wrong in

```
np.arange(40, -40, 4)
```

It is not giving any result.

If you are trying to get number from `-40` to `40` with gap of `4` number then you may try this:

```
import numpy as np

np.arange(-40,40,4)
```

Or from `40` to `-40` with gap of `4` number then this:

```
np.arange(40,-40,-4))
```

Take a look at [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) how to use `arange`.